# SVN: Ignore externals when committing

Tags: svn, svn-externals, svnignore

Is it possible to ignore the commit of externals in SVN?

**Example:**

I have a project and one of the subfolders is an external:

```
svn:externals
my_remote_folder http://svn.whatever.org/blah/trunk/
```

This works seamlessly. Always when I perform an update, the externals get updated as well.

But when I change anything in the local checkout of this external my IDE recognizes the change and offers me the file to commit. But maybe I have just read-access to the external SVN.

I tried to ignore the folder conventionally:

```
svn:ignore
my_remote_folder
```

I also tried

```
my_remote_folder .
```

But my IDE (PhpStorm) and also TortoiseSVN still ignore this ignore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer highly depends on which client you use.

- **Command Line Client**: by default, the command line client does not include externals during commits. From the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html):

  > [...] if you want to commit changes that you've made in one or more of those external working copies, you must run *svn commit* explicitly on those working copies — committing on the primary working copy will not recurse into any external ones.
- **TortoiseSVN**: In the commit dialogue, you can easily deselect files from externals: [image: TSVN Commit Dialogue]
- **PhpStorm**: I cannot tell here, since I don't know the IDE personally.

Comment: Thanks! PhpStorm doesn't provide such a checkbox. You have to disable changed files in externals manually, if you don't want to commit them.

Comment: For TortoiseSVN, it doesn't work if externals are on the same repository

Comment: If someone also experiences a disabled "Show externals from different repositories" check box (just like in the above screenshot), [Stefan Küng suggests to change the timeout to zero (or one)](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.subversion.tortoisesvn.user/26272). Unfortunately this seems to _not_ work on my system, but maybe it is some help to others. He suggests: **1. Settings Dialog → Dialogs 2. 2. Set the "Timeout in seconds to stop the auto-completion parsing" to zero. Seems the regex is choking on one of your files.**

Comment: @UweKeim, I have the exact same issue as the screenshot: grayed out checkbox.  Anyone else has an idea about that?